# Open GL Rotation

Tags: c++, opengl

i'm trying to draw 100 arrows in a grid and trying to rotate each arrow according to the size of the input i read. But here when i try to rotate one arrow, all the arrows rotate at once with it. whats wrong with it ?

```
void drawArrow(void) {

    float y1 = 2.0;
    float y2 = 2.15;
    float y3 = 2.4;


    int count2 = 0;
    for (float col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        y1 -= 0.5;

        y2 -= 0.5;
        y3 -= 0.5;


        float x1 = -2.25;
        float x2 = -2.20;
        float x3 = -2.15;
        float x4 = -2.35;
        float x5 = -2.30;

        for (float rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {

            glPushMatrix(); 


            glTranslatef(-0.35 + 0.5 - 0.1, 0.4 - 0.01 + 0.1, 0.0);

            float m = (windx[count2] * windx[count2]) + (windy[count2] * windy[count2]);
            float rotator = sqrt(m);
            glRotatef(rotator-50, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

            glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);//start drawing a line loop

            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(x2, y2, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(x3, y2, 0.0f); // drawing a arrow
            glVertex3f(x1, y3, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(x4, y2, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(x5, y2, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0.0f);

            x1 += .5;
            x2 += .5;
            x3 += .5;
            x4 += .5;
            x5 += .5;
            count2 ++;
            glEnd();//end drawing of line loop 
            glPopMatrix();
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT  
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE); // Set up a basic display buffer (only single buffered for now)  
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 800); // Set the width and height of the window  
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); // Set the position of the window  
    glutCreateWindow("Weather Analysis"); // Set the title for the window  
    readDataFile();             //Read Data From File
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" for rendering  

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // Tell GLUT to use the method "reshape" for reshaping  



    glutMainLoop(); // Enter GLUT's main loop 
    void reshape(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height); // Set our viewport to the size of our window  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Switch to the projection matrix so that we can manipulate how our scene is viewed  
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset the projection matrix to the identity matrix so that we don't get any artifacts (cleaning up)  
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 100.0); // Set the Field of view angle (in degrees), the aspect ratio of our window, and the new and far planes  
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Switch back to the model view matrix, so that we can start drawing shapes correctly  
}

void display(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Clear the background of our window to red  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer (more buffers later on)  
    glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations  

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.5f, -6.0f);

    renderPrimitive(); // Render the primitive  
    drawArrow();
    glFlush(); // Flush 
}
```

and ALSO i dont know what to enter in the GLtranslatef method. Im really a beginner, sorry.[image]

Comment: A first error is: You have to rotate while your mesh is on the origin, so to be clear, you have to rotate prior to translate. There should be another error in the rest of your code, could you show more context?

Comment: hi, check out now. its a lot messy, please dont mind

Comment: You have to reorganize transformations. Because your arrows have to be rotated (always on (0,0,0)) You need to compute a `x` and a `y` that you increment between passes. => 1: for (rows...) 2: LoadIdentity 3:  compute absolute x and y (in world space) 4: rotate 5: translate(x,y,0) 6: draw

Comment: I dont know if it's very clear for you. For now, you use opengl matrix stack to hold translations, what you need is an absolute x and y in world space and to reload identity matrice for each arrow, to be able to rotate it on the origin

Comment: First start stopping using deprecated functionality! :-)

Comment: i get that all arrows are rotation from one point, but how do i change it ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

Try to draw your arrow in one rutine lets call it `DrawArrow` I suggest it size must be between `[-1.0f; 1.0f]` than place it at the proper position using affine transform first of all translation secondly rotation.

```
void DrawArrow(void)
{
    float x1 = 0;
    float x2 = -0.05;
    float x3 = -0.1;
    float x4 = 0.1;
    float x5 = 0.05;

    float y1 = -0.15;
    float y2 = 0;
    float y3 = 0.15;


    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);//start drawing a line loop

        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(x3, y2, 0.0f); // drawing a arrow
        glVertex3f(x1, y3, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(x4, y2, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(x5, y2, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0.0f);

    glEnd();//
}
```

Than your array drawing function like this (you may correct inacurrances):

```
void drawArrows(void) {
    float y1 = 2.0;


    int count2 = 0;
    for (float col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        y1 -= 0.5;

        float x1 = -2.25;

        for (float rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {

            glPushMatrix(); 

            glTranslatef(x1, y1, 0.0);

            float m = (windx[count2] * windx[count2]) + (windy[count2] * windy[count2]);
            float rotator = sqrt(m);
            glRotatef(rotator-50, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

            DrawArrow();

            x1 += .5;

            count2 ++;
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

I have made some tests the result will be like this (with constant rotator).

[image]

Comment: and what if you rotate first, it's seems strange to me that it is working this way...

Comment: @j-p: it mean you rotate coord axis than they points to other positions  (vector) than (1, 0) and (0, 1) and when you translate objects it will be translated through this new axis.

Comment: @j-p: axis orientation will lost previous basis (|_) became for example (\/) (sory for lost orthogonality), and new object will be translared consider new origin orientation.

Comment: @Mykola: Opengl use row-major storage for matrices, I missed it...I use col-major (opentk) most of the time...(http://www.opentk.com/node/2794)

Comment: @j-p: OpenGL transformations use tranposed matrices as standard matrix representation. The only way to use row major matrices is to call `glLoadTransposeMatrix` or `glMultTransposeMatrix`.

Comment: @j-p: I agree with you about openTK example as in shader you may use any kind of matrix respresentation, because you decide how to multiply vectors to matrix, in fixed pipeline you simply cannot do that thing.

Comment: @Mykola: my bad, it's the opposite, gl use col major and tk row major, sorry